# Running a gulp task after build is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to build out a project and then have it run my 'sftp' task to upload the project when its done with gulp. My project is structured similarly as below. I have a few tasks running to 'build' the project and then want it to upload when its complete. I have the SFTP task working properly it's just the async issue.

```
// I want build:all to run first
gulp.task('build:all', ['one', 'two', 'three'], function(cb) {
    cb(err);
});

// I want SFTP to run after build:all is done
gulp.task('sftp', ['build:all'], function() {

    // upload some files

});

// on task build just run everything
gulp.task('build', ['sftp']);


gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I think we need to see the inside of your `sftp` task. And why does `build:all` always pass an error to the callback function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cb` argument when you want to do some async task:

```
// I want SFTP to run after build:all is done
gulp.task('sftp', ['build:all'], function(cb) {
    doSomeAsyncUpload().then(function(){
        cb()
    })
});
```

And `build` will be runned only after `sftp` calls `cb`

Comment: `doSomeAsyncUpload().then(cb);`

Comment: It's not a good approach. In this variant a result of the promise will be be sended to the callback. But gulp expects argument in the callback only when there is some error (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support). So, if your promise will be resolved to `true` (which determines that all is ok and the async task is successfully finished, for example), it will be putted to the callback and gulp will interpret it as an error.